# How can I stick text to the screen?

Tags: godot

How can I stick text to the screen?

I have a Player (Node/Node2D/KinematicBody2D) to which Camera2D is attached.
And I have Label (Node/Control/Label).

I want the text to always be on the screen, like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDkq4.png).

When a player moves, the label
[stays on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Yp8.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do it is to use a `CanvasLayer` (or multiple `CanvasLayer`). The gist of it is that the `Camera` will be limited to its canvas layer, so all you need to do is to put the UI inside a `CanvasLayer` separate from the world.

---

A more complex, yet more versatile way to do it is to use a `Viewport`. The idea is that you will put the game world inside a `Viewport`, and that `Viewport` will be inside a `ViewportContainer`. This will allow you to have a different resolution for the game world and the UI, which might be useful for pixelart games. See [How to make a silky smooth camera for pixelart games in Godot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxVQsi9wnw8).

Comment: Something like about CanvasLayer was written to me in discord, but this does not work when turned on `current` in camera2d. (I was told so but when the camera does not move then the text does not move behind it either ....)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://i.imgur.com/yuCMCOX.png) help

Comment: I was misunderstood in Discord, so I'll tell you more about what I want.

I want have a health counter on the top left side, why [attached to the screen](https://i.imgur.com/obyMyHe.png) like in old indie games.

But this does not help and IDK why.

I had a [video](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/212250894228652034/979500535117926420/2022-05-27_00-42-44.mkv) where can see, text does not chase the camera.

Comment: @Minari.Nivara Set the property `follow_viewport_enable`  of the `CanvasLayer` to `false` (which is the default). I see in the video you set it to `true`.

Comment: when follow_viewport_enable false then text not [displaying](https://i.imgur.com/I5EKD5w.png)

Comment: @Minari.Nivara It must be out of view. Instead of positioning the `Label` for the camera (which it will not be following anyway), position it from the origin. The origin will be the top left of the screen. Or, you know, use the "Layout" menu that appears on the top when you have a `Control` selected.

Comment: Oh, Thanks for the explanation!
I created a label by coordinates >_<